# What harm could come from reassembling the iPhone home button without the "spring contact backing"?

Tags: iphone, repair, hardware

I got a replacement screen for my first-generation iPhone SE, and I followed the [iFixit guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iPhone+SE+Screen+Replacement/61305) to do the replacement.

Step 23 of the guide mentions a "spring contact backing" part which is supposed to be screwed in between the home button cable and the screen. The spring contact backing is about 3mm wide and looks like this:

[image]

I spent over an hour trying to screw it in between the home button cable and the screen, and every time I started turning the captive screw, it moved out of position. (Looking at the comments on Step 23, I am not the only person who found it to be a frustrating and impossible task.) I finally gave up and just screwed the home button cable to the screen without the spring contact backing.

The phone and home button seem to be working fine without the spring contact backing. But could there be any long term consequences without it? Surely Apple had a reason to put the spring contact backing in between the home button cable and the screen.

Comment: While we can certainly take a stab at this your **best bet** is to ask this on the iFixit forums as it is an iFixit kit and the people there (presumably) have experience with it. **Also** have you contacted iFixit support?

Comment: One would imagine if the component was unnecessary, it wouldn't be there in the first place.